# Azure RemoteApp additional files

Tags: azure, remoteapp

I've just created my first remote app. I choosed my own application .exe file from my desktop and it has been published. Then i connect by Azure connect program and saw my app icon there, unfortunately there was some error when wanted to lunch it. I think the problem is because my program requires also some .dll libraries to be attached and published with this .exe. However i have no idea how to add them to already published app. Can you please tell me how can i do that? Second case - i suppose this published app using storage - how can i check which storage (i have only one already) has been associate with this app and alternatively how to switch to new storage i just created?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to update a custom application published to Azure RemoteApp.
According to Azure RemoteApp documentation:

> if you are using a custom image (either that you built from scratch or
>   that you created by modifying one of our images), you are in charge of
>   maintaining the image and apps.[1](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/remoteapp-update/)

You can follow below steps to update your app:

1. Create a VM using the image from which you have created the RemoteApp Collection. You'll find your custom application on the newly created VM.
2. Update your custom application.
3. Create a new image of the VM.
4. Update RemoteApp with the new image. [Steps for updating the RemoteApp Collection](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/remoteapp-update/)

At the moment Azure RemoteApps does not support updating the custom apps without having to update the server image.

As far as your issue with Storage is concerned, you have to check the Storage account connection string which is used in the application code.